# pthread_attr_setinheritsched for sched_setscheduler

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, thread-priority

I try to test one application which will run several threads with different priority , so the following is my test ap , run in linux x86_64 :

```
pthread_spinlock_t orderspinlock ;
int iGlbCnt=0 ;

void * donothing(void *arg)
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init (&attr);
    //int s = pthread_attr_setinheritsched (&attr, PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED );
    int s = pthread_attr_setinheritsched (&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED  );
    if( s != 0 ){
        printf("pthread_attr_setinheritsched error \n");
        exit(0) ;
    }

    int ipriority = (int)(long) arg ;
    const char *sched_policy[] = {
    "SCHED_OTHER",
    "SCHED_FIFO",
    "SCHED_RR",
    "SCHED_BATCH"
    };
    struct sched_param sp = {
        .sched_priority = ipriority
    };
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("pid=(%d)\n",pid);
    sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_RR, &sp);
    printf("Scheduler Policy is %s.\n", sched_policy[sched_getscheduler(pid)]);

    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    int icnt=0;
    while(1){
        usleep( 1 ) ;
        pthread_spin_lock(&orderspinlock) ;
        iGlbCnt++ ;
        pthread_spin_unlock(&orderspinlock) ;
        if( ++icnt > 10000000 )
             break;
    }
    printf("thread done...(%d)\n",iGlbCnt);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_spin_init(&orderspinlock, 0);

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init (&attr);
    //int s = pthread_attr_setinheritsched (&attr, PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED );
    int s = pthread_attr_setinheritsched (&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED  );
    if( s != 0 ){
        printf("pthread_attr_setinheritsched error \n");
        exit(0) ;
    }

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &donothing, (void *)(long) 80);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &donothing, (void *)(long) 10);
    while( 1 )
        sleep( 5 ) ;
}
```

and g++ --std=c++11 y.cpp -pthread -o y.exe

run :

```
sudo chrt -r -v 66 ./y.exe
```

another terminal watch the threads by

```
 top -H -p `pidof y.exe`
```

I see the threads PR are -67  , -67 , -11 , after both donothing threads die ,
the main thread PR = -11  ,  What should I do so that all three threads 
priority are -81 , -11 , -67  and the main thread keep in -67  to the end ?!

Edit :

```
int policy = 2 ;
s = pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(),policy,&sp) ;
```

instead of  :

```
pid_t pid = getpid();
sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_RR, &sp);
```

look work fine to me .

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, what you want to do is to call `pthread_setschedparam` instead of `sched_setscheduler`.

Comment: @Mine , thanks , I will try it .